# Android jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu Layout Error

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using [jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/)...

On the image below it's a screen capture of the error. 
Note that as I slide close the menu the menu contents shows on top of the content activity.

I'm using the XML implementation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu xmlns:sliding="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/slidingmenulayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        sliding:viewAbove="@layout/activity_start"
        sliding:viewBehind="@layout/activity_menu"
        sliding:touchModeAbove="fullscreen"
        sliding:behindScrollScale="@dimen/behind_scroll_scale"
        sliding:behindOffset="@dimen/behind_offset"
        sliding:shadowDrawable="@drawable/shadow"
        sliding:shadowWidth="@dimen/shadow_width"
        sliding:selectorEnabled="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

@layout/activity_menu:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_menu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Main_Activity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity{

    private SlidingMenu menu;
    private ActionBar action;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MenuClass menu_data[] = populateMenuData();     

        MenuAdapter adapter = new MenuAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_row_item, menu_data);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_menu);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        menu = (SlidingMenu) findViewById(R.id.slidingmenulayout);

        menu.setFadeEnabled(true);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);

        action = getSupportActionBar();
        action.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        menu.setBehindCanvasTransformer(new CanvasTransformer() {
            @Override
            public void transformCanvas(Canvas canvas, float percentOpen) {
                float scale = (float) (percentOpen * 0.25 + 0.75);
                canvas.scale(scale, scale, canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2);
            }
        });
    }
```

Can anyone help me with it or tell me what I'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

I had more success using this library.
https://github.com/iPaulPro/SlidingMenu

It provides backward compatability with pre 3.0 devices.  I have been working with it for several weeks and have been very happy.

I tried the library you are using, and got it to work, but ran into problems when the device rotated etc...

Hope that helps.